# How to get Email Notifications on every upload in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I need to send email notifications to either a group or user on every upload to the site in Alfresco 4.0.

I have setup the SMTP for email and its working fine.

Comment: Can you not just set a rule on the document library root folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gagravarr is right. Create a rule on either the documentLibrary folder for a specific site, the Sites folder to cover all sites, or Company Home to cover everything. Remember to set the rule to apply to sub-folders. You'll obviously want to set the rule filter appropriately so that it only sends emails for instances of specific content types like cm:content or your own custom content type. For example, you probably don't want to send an email when instances of cm:folder are created or when renditions are created, etc.

Comment: Thanks guyz.. I was able to do it